# Updating MySQL from XML file using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I read many useful answers here and the most of them helped me to create script for importing data from XML file. Problem is that this time i have additional part with images url's witch also needs to be updated into MySQL. 
For now, i update MySQL with data from XML, after that use other script to download needed images. After website with XML feed changed they structure, i have problem to figure out how to update images url in array into MySQL row so i can download images after that. 
Even i choose to download images without updating into MySQL, i also can't download them.

This is XML structure

```
<ArrayOfUnitDTO xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UnitDTO>
    <Category>Category name</Category>
    <code>863</code>
    <Status>Blocked</Status>
    <RefNo>12345</RefNo>
    <Images>
      <Image>
        <Title>Community</Title>
        <ImageURL>http://imageaddress.com/images/watermark.aspx?imageurl=/uf/1015/GroupUpdate/unit/350/350_Image.jpg&amp;width=640&amp;group=1015&amp;module=1&amp;watermarktype=default&amp;position=Center</ImageURL>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <Title>Local Area Image</Title>
        <ImageURL>http://imageaddress.com/images/watermark.aspx?imageurl=/uf/1015/GroupUpdate/unit/631/631_Image.jpg&amp;width=640&amp;group=1015&amp;module=1&amp;watermarktype=default&amp;position=Center</ImageURL>
      </Image>
    </Images>
  </UnitDTO>
</ArrayOfUnitDTO>
```

I am i am using this

```
foreach ($listings ->UnitDTO as $listingInfo) //loop read xml
{
            $RefNo =  $listingInfo->RefNo;
            $Category = $listingInfo->Category;
            $code = $listingInfo->code;
            $Status = $listingInfo->Status;

 mysqli_query($link,"REPLACE INTO UnitDTO (`RefNo`, `Category`, `code`, `Status`) VALUES ('$RefNo', '$Category', '$code', '$Status',)") or die(mysqli_error($link));

}
```

No metter what i tried, i can't import images url into `imageurl` MySQL row in array.

Answer (score 2):

to get image url from above xml you have to run one more foreach loop, try something like below code and use it as per your requirement.

```
foreach ($listings ->UnitDTO as $listingInfo){
    $RefNo =  $listingInfo->RefNo;
    $Category = $listingInfo->Category;
    $code = $listingInfo->code;
    $Status = $listingInfo->Status;
        foreach ($listingInfo->Images->Image as $image){
            echo $image->ImageURL;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ram, thank you for answer. 
Yes, i already run it but only 1st image is downloaded.There are some units with 5 and 6 images. That's main problem.

Comment: it's foreach loop you will get all the images just try it

Comment: I already tried before and tried once again. When i use echo, there are all images but when i update MySQL there are only one image.
If i use INSERT instead REPLACE i am getting error Duplicate entry 'AP3147' for key 'PRIMARY'. So it try to use many times same entries.